# Why is the output of tail recursive factorial is zero for large inputs?

Tags: kotlin, tail-recursion

I am new in learning Kotlin. I try to using tail recursion for calculating factorial in my code, but when I enter `99999`, the output is `0`. Here is my code:

```
fun main(){
    println(factTailRec(99999))
}
tailrec fun factTailRec(number: Int, result: Int = 1): Long{
    return if(number.toInt() == 1){
        result.toLong()
    } else {
        factTailRec(number-1, result*number)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `result` of type `Int` is not sufficient to hold the actual resulting value. You need something like `BigInteger`:

```
import java.math.BigInteger
import java.math.BigInteger.ONE


inline operator fun BigInteger.times(other: Int): BigInteger =
    this.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(other.toLong()))

tailrec fun factTailRec(number: Int, result: BigInteger = ONE): BigInteger {
    return if (number == 1) {
        result
    } else {
        factTailRec(number - 1, result * number)
    }
}

fun main() {
    println(factTailRec(99999)) // 28242294079...
}
```

Comment: I think Kotlin has overloaded operators for `BigInteger` so you could avoid using `multiply` and just use `*`: `factTailRec(number - 1, result * number.toBigInteger())`